# Top Ten Security Weaknesses of a Networked Computer

Tags: network, operating-systems

I'm looking for a list of what you would consider to be the Top Ten Security Weaknesses of a Networked Computer, can be Windows or Linux specific but ones that apply to both are better.

I'm not as interested in particular vulnerabilities (aka not answers like MS08-67), rather generic attack vectors which could feature a vulnerability.

Many Thanks,
-Tech

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only came up with 5 so far.

Here is my list in no particular order:

**1. Security Misconfiguration ([OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main))**

```
Good security requires having a secure configuration defined and deployed for the 
application, frameworks, application server, web server, database server, and platform. 
All these settings should be defined, implemented, and maintained as many are not 
shipped with secure defaults. This includes keeping all software up to date, including 
all code libraries used by the application.
```

**2. Insufficient transport layer protection ([OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main))**

```
Applications frequently fail to authenticate, encrypt, and protect the confidentiality 
and integrity of sensitive network traffic. When they do, they sometimes support weak 
algorithms, use expired or invalid certificates, or do not use them correctly.

This allows for packet sniffing.
```

**3. Zero day exploits in software**

```
Networked machines usually provide some kind of service, whether it be a SQL server, 
webserver or FTP server. Vulnerabilities in software will always be a threat as software 
never be developed without security issues.

Vulnerabilities that come under this is for example:
* SQL injection on a database
* XXS on a webserver
* Buffer overflow attacks on an application
* Format string attacks
* ...
```

**4. Hijacking / Spoofing / Session replay**

```
If a middleman is in some way able to observe the traffic between two nodes on a network 
he may try to capture the traffic, modify it and appear as the sender. 

Techniques such as ARP Poisoning comes unde rthis category.
```

**5. Denial of service**

```
Disruption of service by some kind of resource starvation on the victim. I.e packet 
flooding to consume all half-open TCP connections or consuming all bandwith on a 
webserver.
```